# No window opens up in kivy just showing kivy icon

Tags: python, windows, kivy

When I run my kivy script,script runs without errors but I see no open window only a kivy icon in the task bar and it is not possible to open window.

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43F9w.png)

This my code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello 
World',halign='center')


if __name__=='__main__':
    Test().run()
```

Comment: Do you run this inside a virtual machine? Kivy does not work if you don't run it on Hardware Directly

Comment: I'm running it on hardware directly

Comment: Well I tested it with python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22 and it worked perfectly fine :/

Comment: Which Python Version do you use, kivy version and I assume you are using win 10

Comment: Python 3.9.0,kivy 2.1.0, and I'm using win 10

Comment: Well all I could find is that there could be Problems with your graphicsdrivers or that you are running as VNC/RDP Remote Session where it will also not work. Sry I can't help much either Good Luck

Comment: Kivy was working fine the last week,this problem occured today